# I want to check the time interval

Tags: java, android, time

I want to check the interval B, whether it is in the interval A or not?
Is my solution correct?

solution:

```
Date fromA;
Data toA;
Date fromB;
Date toB;
if(fromA.getTime() <= fromB.getTime() &&  toB.getTime() <= toA.getTime()){
// true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code checks if B is in A, not the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

*Answer, should you mean **(non-)overlapping** ranges (instead of being fully contained inside an other range):*

Easiest to see correctness is excluding ranges; and then negate the condition.

Ranges (a1, a2) and (b1, b2):

```
boolean excluding = a2 <= b1 || b2 <= a1
boolean overlapping = a2 > b1 && b2 > a1    // Negation
```

So there is a cross-over end from one is compared to the start of the other.

You code must be wrong. Correct:

```
if (tomA.getTime() >= fromB.getTime() &&  toB.getTime() >= fromAgetTime()) {
```

As `getTime()` return a long, ms sind 1970, there might at one point be signed overflow.
Very theoretical, but not so nice.

Better would be to use the port of the new java.time API, which offer more functionality,
and would make the condition readable.

Comment: I interpreted "B is in the interval A" as B is a subset of A. If this is the right interpretation, OPs condition is correct.

Comment: @Henry you're right; all my use-cases concerned overlapping, not containment. I'll add a concerning text to my answer.